# While trying to refer dropbox API (Dropbox.Api.6.0.1) from my .NET project, I get the following error

Tags: .net, vb.net, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

While trying to refer Dropbox API  (Dropbox.Api.6.0.1) from my .NET project, I get the following error.

> Could not install package 'Dropbox.Api 6.0.1'. You are trying to
> install this package into a project that targets
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain  any
> assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
> framework.  For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 0):

[As of v6.0.0, the Dropbox .NET SDK no longer supports .NET Framework v4.5](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/releases/tag/v6.0.0):

> This release drops support for .NET Framework 4.5. The SDK now solely targets .NET Standard 2.0, which is implemented by .NET Framework 4.6.1 and onwards. If you are using an earlier framework, please consider upgrading.